# Eclipse hangs when application context fails to load using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: eclipse, macos, spring, applicationcontext

For some reason, Eclipse is giving me #@$%.

**First, some Basic info:**
Currently I'm using Eclipse Kepler, on a Mac with OS 10.8.4, 4CPUs and 16GB RAM.
Additionally, I'm using the Spring 3.1.0-Release version.

All I'm doing is running an Integration Test using the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner class, this is a test to see the application context can be loaded:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { TestConfiguration.TestApplicationContextFile })
public class InitIT {

    @Test
    public void testInit() {
    }
}
```

What happens when the application context has a problem (for instance, someone forgot to put a @Component annotation on a class and we get a "BeanCreationException"), eclipse simply freezes and refuses to do anything.
I can't even see the stacktrace, so I can't see what the problem is, and Eclipse just uses 100%+ of CPU and hangs, not even letting me press "Stop".

This doesn't happen every time, but when it does it's very consistent.
Also, needless to say, when the application context is loaded successfully, everything runs smoothly, so it's only a matter of when there's a problem.

Something I've discovered that may give a clue is that when I simply load the application context from a Main function instead of using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, then it's a bit better, but it still takes Eclipse a few minutes to "cool down" and be nice enough to show me the stack trace.

Any ideas? Please let me know if I could send any more info that could help
:)

Thanks!
Ido